# Identify objects in for each loop and eliminate objects with same number using <xsl:copy-of select condtion?

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my input

```
<someAccounts>
    <Account>
           <type>ABC</type>
           <number>123456789</number>               
           <productCode>011</productCode>
           <packageCode>022</packageCode>
        </Account>
       <Account>
           <type>BBC</type>
           <number>234567890</number>               
           <productCode>011</productCode>
           <packageCode>022</packageCode>
        </Account>
       <Account>
           <type>CBC</type>
           <number>345678900</number>               
           <productCode>011</productCode>
           <packageCode>022</packageCode>
        </Account>
        <Account>
           <type>DBC</type>
           <number>999999999</number>               
           <productCode>011</productCode>
           <packageCode>022</packageCode>
        </Account>
       <Account>
           <type>FBC</type>
           <number>999999999</number>               
           <productCode>011</productCode>
           <packageCode>022</packageCode>
        </Account>
  </someAccounts>
```

There are 2 account objects in this which have same number. I want to eliminate both the account objects which have same number ( not just one ) . Basically this should be my output

```
<someAccounts>
 <Account>
           <type>ABC</type>
           <number>123456789</number>               
           <productCode>011</productCode>
           <packageCode>022</packageCode>
        </Account>
       <Account>
           <type>BBC</type>
           <number>234567890</number>               
           <productCode>011</productCode>
           <packageCode>022</packageCode>
        </Account>
       <Account>
           <type>CBC</type>
           <number>345678900</number>               
           <productCode>011</productCode>
           <packageCode>022</packageCode>
        </Account>
  </someAccounts>
```

I tried using this

```
        <xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:copy-of select="someAccounts/Account[number != current()/number]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

this only eliminates duplicate one , but I need both account to be removed, how do I achieve this. Please help

Comment: This can be done by grouping and only copying groups whose size is one. Grouping, however, is implemented very differently in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0. So we have to know which one is your preference.

Comment: Thank you Marcus for your reply. If you can show me in XSLT 1.0  that would be great, I would appricate if you can provide an example for this, thank you so much

Comment: Hi Marcus, I tried this, still cant get it work                          <xsl:key name="byNumber" use="." match="$CifInvestmentAccount/number"/>  
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$CifInvestmentAccount" mode="groupingTemplate"/>
   </xsl:template>  
   <xsl:template mode="groupingTemplate" match="$CifInvestmentAccount">  
     <xsl:for-each select="$CifInvestmentAccount/number[count(.|key('byNumber',.)[1])=1]">  
     <xsl:sort select="."/>  
      <xsl:if test="count(.)=0">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: Is this already referring to my answer?

Comment: yep, thanks Marcus, I didn't see your answer before posting my comment :-)

Comment: There is only one set of `Account` nodes with a duplicate number - `999999999`. There is another which is close, but *not the same*: `234567890` and `345678900`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres another simpler solution, based on the assumption that if the value of the `number` element has occured in *any prior* `Account` then that `Account`is not copied across. Basically, this is the identity transform with this one additional template:

```
<xsl:template match="Account[./number=preceding-sibling::*/number]"/>
```

In the above, we match for any `Account` element, which has a number that also occurs in a preceding sibling. If so, do nothing. Everything else is copied across.

Here is the full code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Account[./number=preceding-sibling::*/number]"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input XMl in the OP, it gives:

```
<someAccounts>
    <Account>
        <type>ABC</type>
        <number>123456789</number>
        <productCode>011</productCode>
        <packageCode>022</packageCode>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <type>BBC</type>
        <number>234567890</number>
        <productCode>011</productCode>
        <packageCode>022</packageCode>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <type>CBC</type>
        <number>345678900</number>
        <productCode>011</productCode>
        <packageCode>022</packageCode>
    </Account>
    <Account>
        <type>DBC</type>
        <number>999999999</number>
        <productCode>011</productCode>
        <packageCode>022</packageCode>
    </Account>
</someAccounts>
```

Comment: Thank you Lego, how do I achieve this this with XSLT 2.0 ?

Comment: @user2984940 Most XSLT1.0 *is* XSLT2.0. I can't see 1.0 specific code in my answer, so changing `version="1.0"` to `version="2.0"` should be all you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, you would probably build upon the [XSLT identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy across existing elements in your XML

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This mean you only need to write a template to ignore **Account** elements with duplicate **number** elements. And if you want to check for **Account** elements with duplicate **number** elements, then you can probably define a key to look them up

```
<xsl:key name="account" match="Account" use="number" />
```

With this, you only need this simple template to ignore the duplicates

```
<xsl:template match="Account[key('account', number)[2]]" />
```

i.e. Ignore the **Account** element if there are at least two **Account** elements with the same **number**.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <!-- Key to look up Account elements by their number -->
   <xsl:key name="account" match="Account" use="number" />

   <!-- Ignore Account elements for which there are at least two with the same number -->
   <xsl:template match="Account[key('account', number)[2]]" />    

    <!-- Copy all other elements as-is -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I like how you elegantly exclude the unwanted accounts by defining the empty match rule! In a production code version I would strongly advice some commenting, though. :-)

Comment: I've added some comments!

Comment: Oops, I was rather suggesting this to @user2984940 for his production version. :-) You already explained your approach wonderfully in your introduction.

Comment: Thank you Tim for your answer and explaination, this is very good

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT 1.0 produces the desired output. It uses explicit `for-each` and `if` constructs. The key helps to find the account sets defined by equal numbers. Only sets of size one are copied.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <!-- create key to find the accounts given by a number -->
  <xsl:key name="number_key" match="Account" use="number/text()"/>

  <xsl:template match="/someAccounts">

    <xsl:copy>

      <xsl:for-each select="Account">

        <!-- key('number_key', ./number) returns a set of accounts with a given number -->
        <!-- the next if only copies if the this set has size = 1 -->

        <xsl:if test="count(key('number_key', ./number)) = 1">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>

      </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 2.0 the `for-each-group` construct can be used to determine the group-size. The structure of the approach remains the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/someAccounts">

    <xsl:copy>

      <xsl:for-each-group select="Account" group-by="number">

        <!-- current-group() returns a set of accounts with a given number -->
        <!-- the next if only copies if the this set has size = 1 -->

        <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) = 1">
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
        </xsl:if>

      </xsl:for-each-group>

    </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Marcus, this is awesome,  Would you also tell me how to do this in XSLT 2.0 please

Comment: You're welcome. In a spare minute take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation.

Comment: yep I will definetly :-)

Comment: Hi Marcus, for the same example above I want to eliminate the duplicate account number with type DBC and retain all the other accounts, how can I do it XSLT2.0 please ?

Comment: Hmmm. I don't quite understand. By picking @LegoStormtroopr's answer you basically state that a template-match oriented approach is what you need. His XSLT 1.0 answer also works for XSLT 2.0 (as he commented) since it is upward-compatible. As for my solution you can easily change it to handle the new case. Have you tried at least?

Comment: yes I used your case in the above scneario,  but I also came across the scenraio when I need to retain one and remove the other from duplicate but I also need to look for the type=DBC element to retain it. This is for my WESB transformation and I need to write my own Custom XSLT for atleast 15 transforms

Comment: Hi Marcus, I like your code below, specially the count to see if there is more than one and eliminate both, but can you tell me how do I look for count if more than one and just pick up the first one and eliminate the second one please ?                                                                                                <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) = 1">
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
        </xsl:if>

Comment: Well, if you just want to take the first one of each group you can simply eliminate the `if` conditional and leave the `copy-of`. This will also work for groups which only have one member in them.

Comment: what if I have to grab the second occurance in the list and ignore the first occurance, how would I do it using for-loop-group ?

Comment: I guess I can use current-group()[2] to grab second occurance

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Please, remember that in case of `[2]` you will need some conditional contruct again since this will be empty if the group has only one element.

Comment: do you see any problems with the below code , I cant get objects which has status Y when the current group is 1. Please help                              <xsl:for-each-group select="$depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount" group-by="number"> 
      <xsl:variable name="stat" select="$depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount/status/text()" />
     <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) = 2">
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>      
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) = 1 and $stat = 'Y'">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>      
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each-group>

Comment: Is this a new question? We should not put too much into the comments of my original answer if we are getting further and further away from the original question.

Comment: your right . I opened a new question , Please helpw me with the below    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031452/need-to-identify-duplicates-with-a-condtional-param-in-xslt1-0

Comment: hi Marcus, any thoughts on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055425/if-else-condition-doesnt-seem-to-evaluate-right-under-for-each-group    ?

Comment: I don't understand. The question has been answered and you picked that answer as primary solution.