# need to identify duplicates with a condtional param in xslt1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Here is my input

```
<depositAccount>
  <EligibleDepAccount>
    <type>DDA</type>
    <market>050</market>
    <number>12345678</number>
    <status>Y</status>
    <relationship>F-N</relationship>
    <productCode>ICK</productCode>
    <packageCode/>
    <primaryIndicator>N</primaryIndicator>
    <customer1DrivBen/>
    <customer2Relationship>O-N</customer2Relationship>
    <customer2DrivBen/>
    <customer3Relationship/>
    <customer3DrivBen/>
    <customer3CifKey/>
    <tierDetail>
      <level>0</level>
      <violationCounter>0</violationCounter>
      <enrollmentDate>0</enrollmentDate>
    </tierDetail>
    <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
  </EligibleDepAccount>
  <EligibleDepAccount>
    <type>DDA</type>
    <market>050</market>
    <number>99999999</number>
    <status>Y</status>
    <relationship>F-N</relationship>
    <productCode>ICK</productCode>
    <packageCode>PDM</packageCode>
    <primaryIndicator>N</primaryIndicator>
    <customer1DrivBen/>
    <customer2Relationship>O-N</customer2Relationship>
    <customer2DrivBen/>
    <customer3Relationship/>
    <customer3DrivBen/>
    <customer3CifKey/>
    <tierDetail>
      <level>0</level>
      <violationCounter>0</violationCounter>
      <enrollmentDate>0</enrollmentDate>
    </tierDetail>
    <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
  </EligibleDepAccount>
  <EligibleDepAccount>
    <type>DDA</type>
    <market>050</market>
    <number>12345678</number>
    <status>N</status>
    <productCode>KDB</productCode>
    <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
  </EligibleDepAccount>
  <EligibleDepAccount>
    <type>DDA</type>
    <market>050</market>
    <number>85677833</number>
    <status>N</status>
    <productCode>KDB</productCode>
    <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
  </EligibleDepAccount>
</depositAccount>
```

I need to find out same account number objects and check if the status is Y , then pull that object. I used the below code

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount" group-by="number">  
  <xsl:variable name="stat" select="$depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount/status/text()" />
  <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) = 2">
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>              
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) = 1 and $stat = 'Y'">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>               
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

In the above code, `test="count(current-group()) = 1 and $stat = 'Y'` doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `for-each-group` but tag the question as `xslt-1.0`, that does not make sense.

Assuming an XSLT 2.0 processor I think you simply want

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount[status = 'Y']" group-by="number"> 
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, this works perfectly, my apologies for putting in as xslt-1.0.   Question, sometimes there may be no duplicates coming in and I still want to capture one element coming in, will this still work ?

Comment: Yes, the `for-each-group` will of course also build groups of single elements if there is only a single one with a certain `number` and the `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` inside the `for-each-group` outputs the first in each group, whether it has only that single element or more does not matter.

Comment: so if I need a condition like say there are 2 same number objects and I want to check status Y which your logic works good, and if I need another condition say if its 1 number object in the group but I dont want to check for status y, how do I do that please ?

Comment: Inside of the `for-each-group` the call `current-group()` gives you a sequence of items in the current group and thus you can check `count(current-group()) gt 1` to check whether there is more than one item in the group and `count(current-group()) eq 1` or `not(current-group()[2])` to check whether there is only one item in the group. If you have further questions consider to ask a new question with the details.

Comment: thnak you Mrtin, I did post a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055425/if-else-condition-doesnt-seem-to-evaluate-right-under-for-each-group    . can you help me with this plesae