# If else condition doesn't seem to evaluate right under for-each-group

Tags: xslt

here is my input xml

```
 <depositAccount>
    <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>12345678</number>
       <status>Y</status>
       <relationship>F-N</relationship>
       <productCode>ICK</productCode>
       <packageCode/>
       <primaryIndicator>N</primaryIndicator>
       <customer1DrivBen/>
       <customer2Relationship>O-N</customer2Relationship>
       <customer2DrivBen/>
       <customer3Relationship/>
       <customer3DrivBen/>
       <customer3CifKey/>
       <tierDetail>
          <level>0</level>
          <violationCounter>0</violationCounter>
          <enrollmentDate>0</enrollmentDate>
       </tierDetail>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
    <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>99999999</number>
       <status>Y</status>
       <relationship>F-N</relationship>
       <productCode>ICK</productCode>
       <packageCode>PDM</packageCode>
       <primaryIndicator>N</primaryIndicator>
       <customer1DrivBen/>
       <customer2Relationship>O-N</customer2Relationship>
       <customer2DrivBen/>
       <customer3Relationship/>
       <customer3DrivBen/>
       <customer3CifKey/>
       <tierDetail>
          <level>0</level>
          <violationCounter>0</violationCounter>
          <enrollmentDate>0</enrollmentDate>
       </tierDetail>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
    <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>12345678</number>
       <status>N</status>
       <productCode>KDB</productCode>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
    <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>85677833</number>
       <status>N</status>
       <productCode>KDB</productCode>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
 </depositAccount>
```

Output should be as below

```
 <depositAccount>
    <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>12345678</number>
       <status>Y</status>
       <relationship>F-N</relationship>
       <productCode>ICK</productCode>
       <packageCode/>
       <primaryIndicator>N</primaryIndicator>
       <customer1DrivBen/>
       <customer2Relationship>O-N</customer2Relationship>
       <customer2DrivBen/>
       <customer3Relationship/>
       <customer3DrivBen/>
       <customer3CifKey/>
       <tierDetail>
          <level>0</level>
          <violationCounter>0</violationCounter>
          <enrollmentDate>0</enrollmentDate>
       </tierDetail>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
    <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>99999999</number>
       <status>Y</status>
       <relationship>F-N</relationship>
       <productCode>ICK</productCode>
       <packageCode>PDM</packageCode>
       <primaryIndicator>N</primaryIndicator>
       <customer1DrivBen/>
       <customer2Relationship>O-N</customer2Relationship>
       <customer2DrivBen/>
       <customer3Relationship/>
       <customer3DrivBen/>
       <customer3CifKey/>
       <tierDetail>
          <level>0</level>
          <violationCounter>0</violationCounter>
          <enrollmentDate>0</enrollmentDate>
       </tierDetail>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>       
    <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>85677833</number>
       <status>N</status>
       <productCode>KDB</productCode>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
 </depositAccount>
```

I have the below code

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount[status = 'Y']" group-by="number">
    <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) = 2 and $depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount[status = 'Y']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>               
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(current-group()[2])">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>               
    </xsl:if>   
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

just doesn't seem to work, output coming back is below which is wrong, what is wrong with the above the xslt code ? I think there are 2 if conditions which is passing though, how can i break if the first test condition is met. please help

```
<depositAccount>
    <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>12345678</number>
       <status>Y</status>
       <relationship>F-N</relationship>
       <productCode>ICK</productCode>
       <packageCode/>
       <primaryIndicator>N</primaryIndicator>
       <customer1DrivBen/>
       <customer2Relationship>O-N</customer2Relationship>
       <customer2DrivBen/>
       <customer3Relationship/>
       <customer3DrivBen/>
       <customer3CifKey/>
       <tierDetail>
          <level>0</level>
          <violationCounter>0</violationCounter>
          <enrollmentDate>0</enrollmentDate>
       </tierDetail>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>        
</depositAccount>
```

Comment: What does your expected result XML look like?

Comment: it should look like the second XML I pasted above with header "Output should be as below". Sorry I was not able to paste that xml in this comments section

Comment: My mistake. I overlooked that you had already added it. No need to paste it in the comments section. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting the same thing in both branches of the conditional, which suggests you might be thinking that select="." will output the current group? Perhaps you want

```
<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
```

Within `xsl:for-each-group`, "." refers to the first item in the current group.

Comment: This still doesnt get me the required output ?                              <xsl:for-each-group select="$depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount" group-by="number">
         <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) = 2 and $depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount[status = 'Y']">
       <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>      
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) = 1">
       <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>      
      </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:for-each-group>

Comment: Please help me on this

Comment: for some reason the condition $depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount[status = 'Y'] is not getting satisfies in the below logic <xsl:if test="count(current-group()) = 2 and $depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount[status = 'Y']">, any thoughts?

Comment: Firstly, you have changed your code since I saw it last. I find it impossible to pursue a thread when the ground is shifting underneath me, it makes a nonsense of my previous answers. In the current form of your code the condition `$depositAccount/EligibleDepAccount[status = 'Y']"` must always be true, because it is the expression used to select the nodes to be grouped, and if there are no nodes to be grouped then the body of the xsl:for-each-group will not be executed.

Comment: all I wanted was "if there are 2 in the group which is based on number, i want to see which one has status y and pick that up" and "if there is one in the group, i want to pick that one no matter of the status" and this one should not occur in my first condition, how do I do this

Comment: Finally! a statement of requirements, rather than just non-working code. So you want something like `if test="count(current-group())=2" then apply-templates select="current-group()[status='Y']"`.

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked now. so I used <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[status='Y']"/> and works, @Martin Honnen did specify this  <xsl:copy-of select="(current-group()[status = 'Y'], .)[1]"/>  and it didn't seem to work, no sure why

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by `number` independent of the `status` but then want to output the first item in each group with `status = 'Y'` or if there are no then the first item you can achieve that as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="depositAccount">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="EligibleDepAccount" group-by="number">
      <xsl:copy-of select="(current-group()[status = 'Y'], .)[1]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given the input

```
<depositAccount>
    <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>12345678</number>
       <status>Y</status>
       <relationship>F-N</relationship>
       <productCode>ICK</productCode>
       <packageCode/>
       <primaryIndicator>N</primaryIndicator>
       <customer1DrivBen/>
       <customer2Relationship>O-N</customer2Relationship>
       <customer2DrivBen/>
       <customer3Relationship/>
       <customer3DrivBen/>
       <customer3CifKey/>
       <tierDetail>
          <level>0</level>
          <violationCounter>0</violationCounter>
          <enrollmentDate>0</enrollmentDate>
       </tierDetail>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
    <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>99999999</number>
       <status>Y</status>
       <relationship>F-N</relationship>
       <productCode>ICK</productCode>
       <packageCode>PDM</packageCode>
       <primaryIndicator>N</primaryIndicator>
       <customer1DrivBen/>
       <customer2Relationship>O-N</customer2Relationship>
       <customer2DrivBen/>
       <customer3Relationship/>
       <customer3DrivBen/>
       <customer3CifKey/>
       <tierDetail>
          <level>0</level>
          <violationCounter>0</violationCounter>
          <enrollmentDate>0</enrollmentDate>
       </tierDetail>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
    <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>12345678</number>
       <status>N</status>
       <productCode>KDB</productCode>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
    <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>85677833</number>
       <status>N</status>
       <productCode>KDB</productCode>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
 </depositAccount>
```

we then get the output

```
<depositAccount>
   <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>12345678</number>
       <status>Y</status>
       <relationship>F-N</relationship>
       <productCode>ICK</productCode>
       <packageCode/>
       <primaryIndicator>N</primaryIndicator>
       <customer1DrivBen/>
       <customer2Relationship>O-N</customer2Relationship>
       <customer2DrivBen/>
       <customer3Relationship/>
       <customer3DrivBen/>
       <customer3CifKey/>
       <tierDetail>
          <level>0</level>
          <violationCounter>0</violationCounter>
          <enrollmentDate>0</enrollmentDate>
       </tierDetail>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
   <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>99999999</number>
       <status>Y</status>
       <relationship>F-N</relationship>
       <productCode>ICK</productCode>
       <packageCode>PDM</packageCode>
       <primaryIndicator>N</primaryIndicator>
       <customer1DrivBen/>
       <customer2Relationship>O-N</customer2Relationship>
       <customer2DrivBen/>
       <customer3Relationship/>
       <customer3DrivBen/>
       <customer3CifKey/>
       <tierDetail>
          <level>0</level>
          <violationCounter>0</violationCounter>
          <enrollmentDate>0</enrollmentDate>
       </tierDetail>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
   <EligibleDepAccount>
       <type>DDA</type>
       <market>050</market>
       <number>85677833</number>
       <status>N</status>
       <productCode>KDB</productCode>
       <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
    </EligibleDepAccount>
</depositAccount>
```

Comment: yes this is the output I am looking for, I will try your solution and let you know, thank you Martin

Comment: no luck, I still get this output, do if you look at the first element it has picked up status N and not Y                                                             <EligibleDepAccount>
        <type>DDA</type>
        <market>050</market>
        <number>12345678</number>
        <status>N</status>
        <productCode>KDB</productCode>
        <TIEligible>false</TIEligible>
     </EligibleDepAccount>    :(

Comment: Which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? I run the code with Saxon 9.5 HE edition and the output I posted is the result Saxon gave.

Comment: this is what i use <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
     xmlns:map="xslt/XSLTransformation4_req_2"
     exclude-result-prefixes="str set math fn dp exsl date map xalan"
     version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="2"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template name="DepositAccountToDepositAccount">
    <xsl:param name="depositAccount"/>
      
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I asked about the XSLT processor you use.

Comment: it uses XSLT Version 1.0

Comment: I am sorry I am new to XSLT, not sure I answered yoru question

Comment: I tried @Michael Kay solution and it worked now. so I used <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[status='Y']"/> and works, your earlier solution is similar except you have used, .)[1] which is  <xsl:copy-of select="(current-group()[status = 'Y'], .)[1]"/>  and it didn't seem to work, no sure why though